# Simulate column span with space in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to simulate a widget that spans over several columns in flutter.

Right now I'm using `Expanded(flex: rowSpan, ...)`, but there is a missing constant space in that calculation that should be added to the relative column width.

I cannot use grid view, as my widget heights will be flexible.

This is what my result looks like:
[image]

As you can see, the "Span 2" example should be 1 space larger.
"Span 3" would be 2 spaces larger.

What I actually want:
[image]